# Is there a statutory basis for rail operators' so called "delay repay" schemes?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, consumer-protection, refund

Fee fi fo fum...

They all have them across the sector, and they seem to be uniformly so named, so I smell an underlying statutory basis. What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

In the EU, [EU Regulation 1371/2007](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2007:315:0014:0041:EN:PDF) dictates, when and how railway companies need to repay you for late times.

[This was incorporated in UK law](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/eur/2007/1371/contents) and is currently still active, but changes are allegedly incoming. Do note that there's a [2020 guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-rail-passengers-rights-and-obligations-regulation-no-13712007), indicating that this regulation became fully enforced on December 4th 2019:

> Regulation 1371/2007 on Rail Passengers’ Rights and Obligations (‘the regulation’) became law in Great Britain (GB) on 4 December 2009, although most parts of it were not initially applied to GB domestic services. The regulation has applied in full to international services from that date.
>
> Allowable exemptions were put in place for domestic services by the government for 2 periods of 5 years under SI 2009/2970 and under SI 2014/2793.
>
> **All parts of the regulation come into effect from 4 December 2019** when the second, five year GB exemption expired **for domestic services**.